# Programmaticaly read and write on PQI Air drive

Tags: android, webdav

I have a [PQI Air drive](http://www.pqigroup.com/news_in.aspx?mnuid=1326&modid=236&nid=153)  and I need to programmaticaly read / write data on this device with android.

The manufacturer offer a proprietary application [S+Flash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pqi.android.splus&hl=fr) which read / write but it can't be used to allow a programmaticaly access.

I can download file via HTTP access, so I tryied to use WEBDAV but it doesn't seem to worm (error 451 or 501), and FTP (connection with anonymous failed with 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home) and also SMB.

Any idea ?

Is it possible to capture the communication made by this application on Android ?

I ran tests with nmap, I got this result :

```
Starting Nmap 5.61TEST4 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-07-23 19:32 Paris, Madrid (heure d&#8217;été)

NSE: Loaded 87 scripts for scanning.

NSE: Script Pre-scanning.

Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 19:32

Scanning 192.168.2.1 [1 port]

Completed ARP Ping Scan at 19:32, 0.20s elapsed (1 total hosts)

Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 19:32

Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 19:32, 16.57s elapsed

Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 19:32

Scanning 192.168.2.1 [1000 ports]

Discovered open port 80/tcp on 192.168.2.1

Discovered open port 8080/tcp on 192.168.2.1

Discovered open port 445/tcp on 192.168.2.1

Discovered open port 139/tcp on 192.168.2.1

Discovered open port 21/tcp on 192.168.2.1

Discovered open port 23/tcp on 192.168.2.1

Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 19:32, 0.48s elapsed (1000 total ports)

Initiating Service scan at 19:32

Scanning 6 services on 192.168.2.1

Completed Service scan at 19:33, 81.51s elapsed (6 services on 1 host)

Initiating OS detection (try #1) against 192.168.2.1

NSE: Script scanning 192.168.2.1.

Initiating NSE at 19:33

Completed NSE at 19:34, 22.12s elapsed

Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1

Host is up (0.016s latency).

Not shown: 994 closed ports

PORT     STATE SERVICE     VERSION

21/tcp   open  ftp         vsftpd 2.0.7

23/tcp   open  telnet      BusyBox telnetd

80/tcp   open  http?

|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 501)

|_http-title: Index of /

139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn Samba smbd 3.X (workgroup: WORKGROUP)

445/tcp  open  netbios-ssn Samba smbd 3.X (workgroup: WORKGROUP)

8080/tcp open  http-proxy?

|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 501)

MAC Address: 00:03:7F:FF:FF:FE (Atheros Communications)

Device type: general purpose

Running: Linux 2.6.X

OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:kernel:2.6

OS details: Linux 2.6.17 - 2.6.36

Uptime guess: 0.021 days (since Mon Jul 23 19:03:20 2012)

Network Distance: 1 hop

TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=203 (Good luck!)

IP ID Sequence Generation: All zeros

Service Info: OS: Unix



Host script results:

| nbstat: 

|   NetBIOS name: WIRELESS_FLASH_, NetBIOS user: &lt;unknown&gt;, NetBIOS MAC: &lt;unknown&gt;

|   Names

|     \x01\x02__MSBROWSE__\x02&lt;01&gt;  Flags: &lt;group&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|     WIRELESS_FLASH_&lt;00&gt;  Flags: &lt;unique&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|     WIRELESS_FLASH_&lt;03&gt;  Flags: &lt;unique&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|     WIRELESS_FLASH_&lt;20&gt;  Flags: &lt;unique&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|     WORKGROUP&lt;1d&gt;        Flags: &lt;unique&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|     WORKGROUP&lt;1e&gt;        Flags: &lt;group&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|_    WORKGROUP&lt;00&gt;        Flags: &lt;group&gt;&lt;active&gt;

|_smbv2-enabled: Server doesn't support SMBv2 protocol

| smb-security-mode: 

|   Account that was used for smb scripts: guest

|   User-level authentication

|   SMB Security: Challenge/response passwords supported

|_  Message signing disabled (dangerous, but default)

| smb-os-discovery: 

|   OS: Unix (Samba 3.3.4)

|   NetBIOS computer name: 

|   Workgroup: 

|_  System time: 1970-01-01 01:35:44 UTC+0
```

Comment: I'm interested in whether you got an answer for this. I am trying to use Air Drive as media server for both my rooted Kindle Fire and iPad. The S+ Flash program will only display .mov or .mp4 files; I'd like to be able to stream .avi. Any thoughts?

Comment: Smb will work. (I don't know why I didn't see it the first time). you have to download application according your device. OMHO vlc can read streamed video on smb.

Answer (score 1):

Try download files by browser from port 8080 to player. iPad - oplayer (internal browser), Android - any: MX, etc.

```
ftp 192.168.100.1   user: root, pass: pqiab
```